# Javascript docs sheets object comparison

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I cant compare javascript object to string, I'm using Google Sheets JavaScript. Data is date but when I checked it with `typeof` it indicated object. Here is my code:

```js
    function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
     .alert('Running My Function');
}
function myFunction() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Taulukko1");
  
  var values = sheet.getRange("A1:K28").getValues();
  
  var row_del = new Array();
 
  for(var i=0;i<values.length; i++)
  {
    if(new Date(values[i][7]).getDate() == new Date('2020-09-17').getDate()){
      row_del.push(i);
    }
  }
  for (var i = row_del.length - 1; i>=0; i--)   {     
    sheet.deleteRow(row_del[i]);   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A date is an object.

### However, you cannot compare dates directly.

To compare dates, the easiest is to convert them to `milliseconds`.

Sample:

```js
if(new Date(values[i][7]).getTime() == new Date('2020-09-17').getTime()){
  // do something
}
```

note the correct formatting.

References:

- [new Date()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)
- [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: There is an error in google sheets as follows: TypeError: Cannot read property '7' of undefined (rivi 30).

Comment: What is the content of your row 30?

Comment: Content is '2020-21-09'

Comment: I would need to see your whole updated code to understand where the error comes from inlcuding the code line number 30.

Comment: But for some reason it won't delete all the rows but some rows.

Comment: Try to implement logs for troubleshooting.